# what is the meaning of "Storm the well" Idiom?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

what does "storm the well" Idiom mean.I tried finding the meaning of it but I couldn't find it.Can any one explain clearly please

Comment: Where did you read this? Can you provide more context please.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner context: Protesting members storm the well. House adjourned till noon.

Comment: The meaning refers to ***storm***: ​
to enter or leave a place in a way that shows that you are angry:
*He stormed out of the house, slamming the door as he went.* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/storm

Comment: Please edit the context which you supply in your comment into the question itself, so potential answerers will notice it.

Answer (score 2):

**To storm something** is to charge towards it, as in an attack; soldiers could **storm** a defensive position occupied by an enemy.

The "well" (now that you've added your comment) is an area in front  of a legislative assembly, before the rostrum from which the speaker addresses the assembly.